# Prove that the given function is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I'm preparing for an exam and can't quite understand the solution given for this question.

Let $X$ be a metric space, $E\subset X$. Define the distance of a point $x \in X$ as 
$$d(x,E)=\inf_{a\in E} d(x,a)\text{.}$$

Prove that the function $f:X \to R, f(x)=d(x,E)$ is uniformly continuous by showing 
$$|d(x,E)-d(y,E)|≤ d(x,y)$$
for any $x,y \in X$.

I've tried applying the Triangle Inequality by assuming that $a=x$ so that $\inf d(x,a)$ is zero. But that seems to be incorrect.

The solution we're given begins with

$$|d(x, E) − d(x, a)| < \varepsilon, |d(y, E) − d(y, b)| < \varepsilon.$$
It follows that
$$|d(x, E) − d(y, E)| ≤ |d(x, a) − d(y, b)| + 2\varepsilon$$

I can't quite understand how I get from the first line to the second.

Comment: A comment on why your approach is wrong: if $x\notin E$, than there is not $a\in E$, such that $a = x$.

Comment: I think I understand that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add and subtract $d(x,a)$ and $d(y,b)$ and use the triangle inequality, together with what you already know:

\begin{align}
|d(x,E) - d(y,E)| &= |d(x,E) - d(x,a) + d(x,a) - d(y,b) + d(y,b) - d(y,E)| \\
&\leq |d(x,E) - d(x,a)| + |d(x,a) - d(y,b)| + |d(y,b) - d(y,E)| \\
&\leq \varepsilon + |d(x,a) - d(y,b)| + \varepsilon
\end{align}

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$|d(x, E) − d(y, E)|=|d(x, E) − d(x, a)+d(x, a) -d(y, E)− d(y,b)+d(y,b)|\\\leq|d(x, E) − d(x, a)|+|d(y, E)− d(y,b)|+|d(x, a)-d(y,b)|\\\leq2\epsilon+|d(x, a)-d(y,b)|$$